# Vectorization or sum as matrix operations

Tags: octave, vectorization

Let there be the following definition of [gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) cost function

[image]

with the hypothesis function defined as

[image]

what I've come up with for multivariate linear regression is

```
theta = theta - alpha * 1/m * ([theta', -1]*[X';y']*X)';
h_theta = 1/(2*m)* (X*theta - y)'*(X*theta-y);
```

*(octave notation, `'` means matrix transpose, `[A, n]` means adding a new column to matrix A with scalar value n, `[A; B]` means appending matrix B to matrix A row-wise)*

It's doing its job correctly how far I can tell (the plots look ok), however I have a strong feeling that it's unnecessarily complicated.

How to write it with as little matrix operations as possible (and no element-wise operations, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is unnecessarily complicated, and instead this is what you want. Matrix operations are good because you don't have to loop over elements yourself or do element-wise operations. I remember taking a course online and my solution seems pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it is the most efficient way of doing it as it is fully vectorized. It can be done by having a for loop over the summation and so on, however this is very inefficient in terms of processing power.